# What's the difference between `auto pp` and `auto *ppp`?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, auto

```
int foo = 11;
int *p = &foo;

auto pp = p;
auto *ppp = p;

cout << pp << endl;
cout << ppp << endl;
```

This program will produce the same output for `pp` and `ppp`, but why? `auto` deduces the variable should be `int`, so I think the declaration of `ppp` is right. But `pp` and `ppp` have the same value...

Output:

```
0x61fefc
0x61fefc
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the particular example you show, there is no difference. But imagine you would later on add two `const` qualifier like the following:

```
const auto pp = p;
const auto *ppp = p;
```

Is it still the same? Turns out that this is identical to

```
int * const pp = p; // pointer is readonly
const int *ppp = p; // pointer is readonly
```

because in `auto pp = p`, `auto` matches `int*` as a whole, and `const` modifies what's on its left (or what's on its right, if there is nothing on its left). Contrary, in `auto *ppp = p`, `auto` matches `int`, and this is what `const` applies to.

Because of this notable difference and because we should use `const` variables whenever possible, I'd advise you to always use `auto*` when using type deduction for pointer variables. There is no way to `const`-qualify the pointer itself instead of the pointee, and if you want to `const`-qualify both, this is possible by

```
const auto * const pppp = p;
```

which doesn't work without the `*`.

Comment: Subtle, and important to know, and I don't recall reading this in any recent C++ book, e.g., Stroustrup's `Tour` 2nd ed.  (I may have missed it.)

Comment: Actually you didn't add const qualifier _to both variables_. You instead added it to the first variable and to the pointee of the second one.

Comment: @davidbak I agree, this is not super obvious. It bit me once, and as painful learning is quite effective, I remember since then :)

Comment: Yepppp! _Painful learning is quite effective_ but unfortunately time consuming (and sometimes frustrating). Reading a nice explanation (making things obvious) is the 2nd best option (and much less time consuming).

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference in `auto` and `auto *` in this particular case. In case of `auto pp = p;` type will be deduced to `int *` while in case of `auto *ppp = p;` type will be deduced to `int`.

[`auto` qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer. [...]

Note that unlike `auto` the `auto *` will deduce only pointer types.

Comment: The key point is `auto` uses template argument deduction rules, and so `auto*` will only deduce pointer types.

Comment: @rustyx; I added *particular case*.